# How do I retain GitHub OAuth scopes persistently between visits?

Tags: github, oauth, scope, github-api

I have a developer application on GitHub. When new users sign into my site, I request the 'admin:repo_hook' scope. They're faced with the GitHub Authorization screen, they hit 'Accept', and they're directed back to my site where they're now signed in.

The user ID, and details of any scopes the user has granted, are stored in my database.

As they start to use my site, I ask for additional scopes as and when necessary, e.g. 'repo_deployment'. To prevent the already granted permissions from being revoked, I pass all current scopes (pulled from the database) along with the new scope request, i.e. 'scope=repo_deployment,admin:repo_hook'. The user is faced with the GitHub Authorization screen again, they grant permissions for repo deployment, and they're directed back to my site.

My problem occurs when the user signs out of my site, and then attempts to sign back in. At sign-in, I have no idea if this is a new user or an existing user.

If I only pass 'admin:repo_hook' as the required scope, then GitHub thinks I want to now *revoke* the 'repo_deployment' scope. But I cannot query the database to see what scopes have already been granted, because I don't know the ID of the user without using OAuth.

I'd be happy to use OAuth, as I can just not pass any scopes, meaning GitHub will not request or revoke any scopes for existing users of my app, which is good. But *new* users would see the Authorization screen requesting a 'public information' scope - and, upon identifying that the user is a new user with no granted scopes, I'd then have to send them to a *second* Authorization screen asking for the 'admin:repo_hook' scope!

Is there a persistent scope tracking solution that lets me ask new users for a specific scope, whilst retaining existing users' scopes, whilst not showing users more Authorization screens than is necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible (says a few hours of personal experimentation).

Happy for someone to provide an answer if there is one, but for now I've compromised and just require multiple scoping requests.